# Close SerialPort Object using C# WPF in safe way

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port, barcode, dispose

I am using RS-232 barcode in my program and it gets me to a new window
The new window also should be able to close itself and open the first window again and let me to using another barcode

My code stuck on this next line: `barcodeManager.Dispose();` What I do wrong?

I will show and important part of my code:
If you need more parts of my code tell me to add

My Main model looks like that:

My main window loop:

```
public FirstWindowMV(Action close)
{
    keepLoop = true;
    this.close = close;
    TblTray_StepInSequence = null;
    tblTray = null;

    do
    {
        if(GetBarcodeData() == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (tblTray != null && TblTray_StepInSequence != null)
        {
            if(OpenMainWindow() == false)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    } while (keepLoop);
}
```

this part of code : `OpenMainWindow()` do some logic

Method to get the barcode:

```
 private bool GetBarcodeData()
        {
            BarcodeSearcher barcodeSearcher = new BarcodeSearcher();
            barcodeSearcher.ShowDialog();
            BarcodeSearcherMV bmv = (BarcodeSearcherMV)barcodeSearcher.DataContext;

            if (bmv.ExitResultDialog == true)
            {
                close();
                keepLoop = false;
            } 
            TblTray_StepInSequence = bmv.TblTray_StepInSequence;
            tblTray = bmv.tblTray;
            Barcode = bmv.Barcode;

            return keepLoop;
        }
```

My BarcodeSearcherMV looks like :

```
public class BarcodeSearcherMV : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool ExitResultDialog;
        public string BarcodeData { get; set; }

        private BarcodeManager barcodeManager;

        private ICommand _Exit;

        public ICommand Exit
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Exit == null)
                {
                    _Exit = new RelayCommand((param) => ExitAction());
                }
                return _Exit;
            }
        }

        private void ExitAction()
        {
            ExitResultDialog = true;
            close();
        }

        public BarcodeSearcherMV()
        {
        }

        public BarcodeSearcherMV(Action close)
        {
            this.close = close;
            barcodeManager = new BarcodeManager(barcodeAction);
        }

        private string barcode;
        private Action close;

        public string Barcode
        {
            get
            {
                return barcode;
            }
            set
            {
                barcode = value;
                barcodeAction(barcode);
            }
        }

        public tblTray_StepInSequence TblTray_StepInSequence;
        public tblTray tblTray;

        private void barcodeAction(string barcode)
        {
            TblTray_StepInSequence = DigatronSQL12ManagerInstance.GetTblTray_StepInSequences(barcode);
            tblTray = DigatronSQL12ManagerInstance.GetTblTray(barcode);
          
            if (TblTray_StepInSequence != null && tblTray  != null)
            {
                this.barcode = barcode;
                barcodeManager.Dispose();
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    close();
                }));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

My BarcodeManager class:

```
   public class BarcodeManager:IDisposable
    {
        private Action<string> barcodeAction;
        //public List<SerialPort> ScanCodeSerialPort { get; set; }
        public SerialPort ScanCodeSerialPort { get; set; }

        public BarcodeManager(Action<string> _barcodeAction)
        {
            barcodeAction = _barcodeAction;
            try
            {
                string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

                SerialPortIniManager SerialPortIniManager = new SerialPortIniManager();
                string portName = SerialPortIniManager.GetCurrentPortName();

                try
                {
                    SerialPortIniManager spim = new SerialPortIniManager();
                    ScanCodeSerialPort = new SerialPort(portName, Convert.ToInt32(spim.GetBaudRate()),
                        (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), spim.GetParity()), Convert.ToInt32(spim.GetDataBits()),
                        (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), spim.GetStopBits()));
                    ScanCodeSerialPort.DataReceived += DataRecive;
                    ScanCodeSerialPort.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                ScanCodeSerialPort = null;
            }
        }
        private void DataRecive(object serialPort, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs _event) { 
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            barcodeAction(((SerialPort)serialPort).ReadExisting().Trim()); 
            }));
        }
        
        public void Dispose()
        {
            
            try
            {
                if (ScanCodeSerialPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    ScanCodeSerialPort.DataReceived -= DataRecive;
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        ScanCodeSerialPort.Close();
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LocalPulserDBManagerInstance.WriteLog(ex.StackTrace, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```

My SerialPortIniManager object :

```
public class SerialPortIniManager : IniBase
    {
        private static readonly string iniPath = @"C:\pulser\GlobalConfig.ini";
        public SerialPortIniManager() : base(iniPath)
        { }

        public string GetBaudRate()
        {
            try
            {
                return GetString("SerialPort", "BaudRate", "9600");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public string GetParity()
        {
            try
            {
                return GetString("SerialPort", "Parity", "None");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public string GetDataBits()
        {
            try
            {
                return GetString("SerialPort", "DataBits", "7");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public string GetStopBits()
        {
            try
            {
                return GetString("SerialPort", "StopBits", "One");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public string GetCurrentPortName()
        {
            try
            {
                return GetString("SerialPort", "CurrentPortName", "COM1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

My ini file : C:\pulser\GlobalConfig.ini

```
[SerialPort]
BaudRate = 9600
Parity = None
DataBits = 7
StopBits = One
CurrentPortName = COM1
```

Picture of Call Stuck on the stuck point

[image]

Comment: Use Debug : Break All.  The check Debug : Windows : Call Stack.  This should tell you where the program is actually stuck.

Comment: @jdweng  Its look like that: https://prnt.sc/tsmm9j

Comment: Did you read first line?  It look like you have a dialog box the is waiting for an enter to continue.

Comment: @jdweng I dont know what is mean...

never mind..  for now I just keep this port open for all the lifetime of the program...  thanks anyway

Comment: You need to make sure that there is no more data coming through when you close the port otherwise it gets stuck because your data received event was still firing characters it saw before you closed the port.